# If a prime and its square both divide a number n, prove that $n=a^2 b^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, prime-factorization

Lets call a number $n$ a *fortified* number if $n>0$ and for every prime number $p$, if $p|n$ then $p^2|n$. Given a *fortified* number, prove that there exists $a,b$ such that $n=a^2b^3$.

I know that this must revolve around the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, but I can't figure out how to do this proof.

Some examples of *fortified* numbers: 1, 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 36, 49, 64, 72, 81, 100, 108, 121, 125, 128, 144, 169, 196, 200

Comment: Do you allow $b$ to be $1$?

Comment: $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ so yes I think $b=1$ is allowed

Comment: @lemons25 Welcome to Math SE. Hint: Can you prove that for every integer $m \ge 2$, there are non-negative integers $c$ and $d$ such that $m = 2c + 3d$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan yes I can!

Comment: Let's not call them *fortified*, they already have two names in the literature, we don't need three. Some people call them *powerful*, some call them *squarefull*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct this is related to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. The statement regarding a *powerful* or *squarefull* (as [Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588794/if-a-prime-and-its-square-both-divide-a-number-n-prove-that-n-a2-b3/3588804#comment7378478_3588794) suggests naming them instead of *fortified*) number means all of its prime factors must have a power of $2$ or larger.

You're asking to prove that all such numbers $n$ can be expressed using natural numbers $a$ and $b$ where

$$n = a^2b^3 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This involves basically proving that for every integer $m \ge 2$, there are non-negative integers $c$ and $d$ such that

$$m = 2c + 3d \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

You state in your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588794/if-a-prime-and-its-square-both-divide-a-number-n-prove-that-n-a2-b3#comment7378475_3588794) you can do this, so I'll leave that to you, as it's fairly easy to do, such as with induction. Also note it's related to a particular case of the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) which shows the maximum number that can't be expressed by \eqref{eq2A} is $a_1 a_2 - a_1 - a_2 = 2(3) - 2 - 3 = 1$, so anything $2$ or larger can.

With this, consider each prime factor $p$ of $n$. Consider the [p-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) function $v_p(m) = e$ which gives, for any prime $p$, the highest exponent $e$ such that $p^{e} \mid m$. Then for any prime factor $p$ of $n$, have $v_p(n) = m$, with $v_p(a) = c$ and $v_p(b) = d$. Do this for all $p \mid n$ to create the corresponding prime factors of $a$ and $b$, and with both $a$ and $b$ not having any other prime factors. You will then end up with \eqref{eq1A}.

Comment: When you say "let $m$ be the power of $p$ in $n$", you mean chose $m$ such that $p^m | n$ right?

Comment: @lemons25 Yes, that is basically what I meant, with $m$ being the largest power where $p^{m} \mid n$. To help make that more clear, I updated my answer to add the detail of "the prime factorization" for the powers.

Comment: @lemons25 As it's more standard in number theory, plus it makes the description more succinct (and possibly easier to follow), I changed the answer again to use the p-adic valuation function.

Comment: +1 for explaining that this is an instance of the coin problem more than anything else.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks a lot. this was great!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. In general, I try to make my answers comprehensive. Also, I agree with you that with this problem, it is basically the coin problem, although somewhat in "disguise" if you will.

Comment: @lemons25 Worth mention this can be done simply directly - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ n = a^2 b^3\, $ for $\,\color{#c00}b=$ product of primes that occur to $\rm\color{#c00}{odd}$ power in $\,n\,$ and $\,a= \sqrt{n/b^3},\,$ an integer since all primes in $\,n/b^3\,$ occur to *even* power, e.g. $\,\color{#c00}2^{\large 7} 3^{\large 4}\color{#c00}5^{\large 3} 7^{\large 2}\! = (2^{\large 2} 3^{\large 2} 7)^{\large 2}\,(\color{#c00}{2\cdot 5})^{\large 3}$

Comment: i.e. to force an odd (expt) $\,> 2\,$ to be even, simply subtract $3$ from it, by moving a  $\,\color{#c00}{p^{\large 3}}\,$ factor into $\,\color{#c00}{b^3}.\,$ It's simply the **squarefree decomposition** of $n = c d^2$ modified to $\, c^3 (d/c)^2$ in the case $\,c\mid d\ \  $

Comment: A simple description. I wasn't looking for one for my first reaction was to view it as a coin problem. Not much difference, but this approach makes the answer more explicit.